# Did not find handler method Error - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, request-mapping

I am currently writing a Spring Boot application and the application starts up fine and I am able to display everything on the web through localhost. However, despite everything working fine the message debug error still shows up in the console log.

This question has come up a few times but I've tried all the solutions and nothing really seems to work.

My packages are laid out like so

com.app.myApplication
com.app.myApplicaiton.controller

and here is an example of how my controller class looks like

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/foods")

public class testClass{

@RequestMapping(value="/spicy", params = {"flavour"})
public String returnJSON(){
return somestuff;
}


}
```

Error Message from Console Log

```
  o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping:Looking up handler method for path 
  /foods/spicy
  o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping:Did not find handler method for 
  [/foods/spicy]
```

Any insights would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the actual error and/or stack trace.

Comment: Is the log saying /food/spicy get mapped?

Comment: parameter  "flavour" is not optional here and must be in the path to invoke the handler

Comment: do you mean update value="/spicy" into something like value="/spicy{flavour}"?

Comment: you can call that endpoint with this url  ..../food/spicy?flavour=myFlavour  . spicy is part of the path and you have to pass a value for the parameter flavour in the url, then you can use that value as falvour in the function

Comment: I'ved tried completely removing all the params and just giving it straight up values, still get the same error

Comment: Where are you getting the error? While running the app or while calling the endpoint?

Comment: after calling the endpoint, it works perfectly fine on the web and display everything correctly, i just keep getting that debug error message

Answer (score 0):

The log message might seem a little misleading. There is nothing wrong with your code and the request mapping is fine. This message is most likely presented by the spring-boot-actuator module which adds a number of endpoints to your project automatically.

Check out https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready